# EIA3216 package. What is it?

Tags: capacitor, eaglecad, packages

On Eagle, I was told that one of my parts was a 10uF cap that was of the EIA3216 package. Can I know what this is? I tried to find such a part online but was unable to do so.

Comment: Raaj, you should change your username to "Raaj" or something you prefer. Rather than add your signature to questions, the SE site does this for you by putting your user icon and associated information at the bottom of the question.

Comment: good point, i have never bothered to change my username

Comment: I don't use Eagle, so I don't know what evil may lurk in its libraries, but it should be up to the user to determine what package he will use for a part.  Perhaps the schematic library you are using has a 10 uF capacitor that specifies a 3216 package.  If you can't buy a 10 uF cap in that package, or if you are making a through-hole board, you should be able to change that package to one that suits the part you intend to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The EIA 3216 is referring to a form factor. For example here are some form factors shown on the [Wikipedia page about surface mount components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface-mount_technology#Packages):

- EIA 3216-10: 3.2 mm × 1.6 mm × 1.0 mm
- EIA 3216-12: 3.2 mm × 1.6 mm × 1.2 mm
- EIA 3216-18: 3.2 mm × 1.6 mm × 1.8 mm

EIA stands for Electronic Industries Alliance, and is a group that develops standards for the electronics manufacturing industry.

Answer (score 1):

EIA 3216 is a standard footprint for Tantalum capacitors that have a size of 3.2 mm × 1.6 mm × 1.0 mm

Wikipedia has a [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface-mount_technology#Packages) of EIA standard footprint